# My laptop doesn't show Sd card, the camera says that it needs to be formated

Tags: nikon, repair, memory-card, nikon-d3100, sdcard

I have a problem with my SD card, a week ago I replaced my SP Silicon power 16GB 10th generation card with another card, when I put it beck into the camera, it said that card needs to be reformatted, I tried to format the card with camera, but couldn't, so I took it out again and put it in my leptop, but the problem is that leptop doesn't read it, it doesn't even show that the SD card is plugged in, so what could be the reason of that? before I did this, I kept the card in my wallet with some coins, could that be a reason? or maybe some virus ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about electronics support unrelated to photography.

Comment: Well electronics is somehow related to photography as I guess and I also found some topics regarding to SD card on this forum, I have a problem and all I'm looking for, is an answer, not some critical comments!

Comment: The use of an SD card in a camera is related to photography.  This is about an SD card failure outside of a camera.  It is most likely simply a crappy quality SD card that was bad to begin with.  If the SD card doesn't work in anything, it generally means it is broken, if it is brand new, it means it was defective.  Return it and actually pay for a decent quality card from a reliable manufacturer. I'm not sure what else you could possibly expect as an answer and it is still in no way related to photography.

Comment: This question is marginally on topic, but not really answerable by us. It's not directly an issue with the camera, so the simple answer is take it back.

Comment: Ok referees, I'll take that into consideration for the next time :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the symptoms you describe a virus is highly unlikely. Physical damage is a high possibility. When placed the card in the wallet, if you then placed the wallet in your back pocket and sat down this could have put significant stress on the card resulting in damage.

If this is the case card is probably beyond economical recovery. If there is any particularly important photos on it, they may be recoverable by expensive specialist companies.

Even if this card does somehow start working, I would not recommend using it. To do so would risk losing your photographs.